# IPv6 for WinINet APIs

Tags: ipv6, wininet

WinINet provides functions such as InternetCanonicalizeUrl, InternetConnect.
I would like to know if these calls work with IPv6 addresses?

In my application, which is using WinINet api for connection with an FTP server, is unable to access FTP server when IPv6 address is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN WinINet supports IPv6 starting with the version bundled with IE7. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385325(v=vs.85).aspx

For URLs, you might need to put the address in square brackets for it to work (there's an example in the link above).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one doubt. Does it mean that I should install IE7 on the system to use IPv6 addresses on WinINet API calls?

Comment: A problem I faced in FTP url is that when IPv6 address is being passed as ftp://user:pass@[IPv6]/file, then '[' and ']' converted to %5B and %5D by InternetCanonicalizeUrl. After that InternetCrackUrl returns and error.

Comment: That would seem like a bug in InternetCanonicalizeUrl(), then. Maybe using a hostname would work? Haven't touched FTP in ages though, and the documentation only mentions HTTP. And no, you shouldn't have to install IE7 specifically, IE8, IE9 or IE10 should work, too.

Comment: I mean to say will it work in Windows XP after installing IE7?

Comment: @dbasic, I can't tell you for sure because I don't have an XP machine. But the documentation specifically says they introduced IPv6 support in IE7, so if your XP machine still has IE6 then logically it shouldn't work and you would need to install IE7. But that part of the documentation doesn't mention FTP, only HTTP. So it's safe to say that it may work with IE7 but it definitely won't work with IE6.